# Simple validation with SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I'm new to sqlalchemy, and I'm trying to achieve simple validation of model's fields, as provided by Django ORM (min & max for Integer, email, ...).
Can SQLAlchemy do this sort of field validations out of the box ?
By the way, I'm using SQLAlchemy with Flask.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

See [Simple Validators](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_1_0/orm/mapped_attributes.html#simple-validators) in the documentation. Sample code extract below:

```
class EmailAddress(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'address'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    email = Column(String)

    @validates('email')
    def validate_email(self, key, address):
        assert '@' in address
        return address
```

Comment: Ok, I've already read this part of the doc. I just wanted to know if there were basic validation built-in, at least something as simple as specifying a range for Integer type. But it seems like there's none.   Thx taking the time to respond van.