# Where can I find a list of the Flask SQLAlchemy Column types and options?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I hope the word "Types" is used correctly here. Perhaps I mean "Arguments". Feel free to edit.

I am creating a database using Models with Flask with SQLAlchemy, where can I find a list of all the different possible Column arguments such as:

`account_id = db.Column(db.Integer, nullable=False)`

I know some of the obvious types such as `db.Integer` or `db.String`. However I can't seem to find in the SQL Alchemy documentation, or the Flask documentation, a list of all possible arguments for creating a `db.Column` instance. Am I looking wrong?

Is there a way of differentiating things like `db.Integer` into tinyint, bigint, etc.?

As for options, such as the `nullable=False`, I have had trouble finding a good list of all the possible options when creating a `db.Column` instance.

Answer (score 63, accepted):

I think you're looking for the [Column and Data Types](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/type_basics.html) page in the documentation.
A little HTML parsing gives:

- ARRAY
- BIGINT
- BINARY
- BLOB
- BOOLEAN
- BigInteger
- Boolean
- CHAR
- CLOB
- Concatenable
- DATE
- DATETIME
- DECIMAL
- Date
- DateTime
- Enum
- FLOAT
- Float
- INT
- INTEGER
- Integer
- Interval
- LargeBinary
- MatchType
- NCHAR
- NVARCHAR
- Numeric
- PickleType
- REAL
- SMALLINT
- SchemaType
- SmallInteger
- String
- TEXT
- TIME
- TIMESTAMP
- Text
- Time
- TypeDecorator
- TypeEnginBases
- TypeEngine
- Unicode
- VARBINARY
- VARCHAR

Comment: Ah. I think I oversaw the options there because I was looking directly after `db.Column`, which is silly because `db` is just the name I used to initialise the database, or however you say it... Thank you!

Comment: On the page you linked, under small integer it has this: 

`__init__(length=None, collation=None, convert_unicode=False, unicode_error=None, _warn_on_bytestring=False)`

Can I therefore conclude that if I type `db.Column(db.SmallInteger, length=5)`, I am defining a small integer with a length of 5, then?

Comment: I think that you should simply try and see the results in the database.

Comment: silly question but which one do I pick for information passed through a radio button?

Answer (score 31):

Documentation is directly perceived through the senses, but if you still wanna see it in commandline, try some IDE, or just type this:
(normally our `db` is just `SQLALCHEMY()`)

```
>>> print dir(sqlalchemy.types)
["ARRAY","BIGINT","BINARY","BLOB","BOOLEAN","BigInteger","Binary","Boolean","CHAR","CLOB","Concatenable","DATE","DATETIME","DECIMAL","Date","DateTime","Enum","FLOAT","Float","INT","INTEGER","Indexable","Integer","Interval","JSON","LargeBinary","MatchType","NCHAR","NULLTYPE","NUMERIC","NVARCHAR","NullType","Numeric","PickleType","REAL","SMALLINT","STRINGTYPE","SchemaType","SmallInteger","String","TEXT","TIME","TIMESTAMP","Text","Time","TypeDecorator","TypeEngine","Unicode","UnicodeText","UserDefinedType","VARBINARY","VARCHAR","Variant"]
```

Comment: I think that you should omit non-types like `'__file__'` and `'_DateAffinity'`

Comment: A quick question. Since I can see on there that `Tinyinteger` doesn't exist, should I therefore just use `SmallInteger` for an integer with a length of 3, for example?

Comment: @k4kuz0 yep, just use SmallInteger, if you want to limit the size of the integer column and you are using mysql ,just see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15804685/sqlalchemy-integer-column-size).or you may validate the length in the validator ,see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8256715/simple-validation-with-sqlalchemy)

Comment: How can we create uuid for for primary key

Answer (score 0):

Here what I found in sqlalchemy/types.py

https://github.com/zzzeek/sqlalchemy/blob/master/lib/sqlalchemy/types.py

Comment: A link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: [add context around the link](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you're linking to in case the target page is unavailable. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted.](//stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers)